# How to programmatically open view for making a selection by clicking on UItextfield for input

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

My question is how would I go about programmatically openning a new partial navigation pane via a click on a UITextfield or UITextview which would allow a user to make a selection and send it back to the calling view? See image below.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619601-textfieldshouldbeginediting) for this like following.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField === myTargetTextField {
            // navigate to your screen
            return false // keyboard won't open
        }
        return true // allows to open the keyboard
    }
}
```

For `UITextView` there's [`UITextViewDelegate.textViewShouldBeginEditing(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate/1618608-textviewshouldbeginediting) which serves the same purpose.